# how to rotate around one specified point in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Could anybody know how to rotate around one specified point in fabric.js? For example,

```
var line1 = new fabric.Line([70, 20, 70, 100], {
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 6
});
```

I would like to rotate it based on its end point(70, 100) but not its center.

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve a rotation about an arbitrary point using `fabric.util.rotatePoint`. This will let you rotate a line (defined by `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2`) about an origin (defined by `origin_x` and `origin_y`) by an angle in degrees (defined by `angle`).

Note that `fabric.util.rotatePoint` takes a rotation in radians, even though `angle`s are usually specified in degrees when using fabric.js.

```
var rotation_origin = new fabric.Point(origin_x, origin_y);
var angle_radians = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(angle);
var start = fabric.util.rotatePoint(new fabric.Point(x1,y1), rotation_origin, angle_radians);
var end = fabric.util.rotatePoint(new fabric.Point(x2,y2), rotation_origin, angle_radians);
var line1 = new fabric.Line([start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y], {
    stroke: '#000000',
    strokeWidth: 6
});
```

You can do the same with other objects, but you may need to provide the `angle` property to rotate the object appropriately.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This solution still works over 7 years later! I was about to do a bunch of trig.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to rotate around arbitrary point at the moment. The origin of transformation — for scaling & rotation — is currently at center of an object. We're planning to add support for arbitrary origins of transformation in the near future.