# Truly rotate center of equilateral triangle in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, fabricjs

Using Fabric.js, I'm having trouble truly rotating a triangle around its center point, or at least what I believe should be the center point. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UW8Be/) that demonstrates. The triangle is simple, and I used `originX: 'center'` and the same for originY, however as the triangle is rotating, there is still slight movement in the x and y directions. How do I make sure that the triangle never moves?

I found this answer and was wondering if this is the right path to take? 
[how to rotate around one specified point in fabric.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829929/how-to-rotate-around-one-specified-point-in-fabric-js)

EDIT: New efforts include implementing the answer from the above linked question. Here's the code:

```
function createTriangle(x, y, angle)
{

    var t = new fabric.Triangle(
    {
        width: 350,
        height: 300,
        selectable: false,
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        left: x,
        top: y,
        angle: angle
    });


    var rotation_origin = new fabric.Point(t.getCenterPoint().x, t.getCenterPoint().y);
    var angle_randians = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(angle);
    var rotatePoint = fabric.util.rotatePoint(new fabric.Point(rotation_origin.x, rotation_origin.y), rotation_origin, angle_randians);

    t.originX = rotatePoint.x;
    t.originY = rotatePoint.y;  
    return t;`
}
```

This, however is not working for me. The triangle still moves a bit while rotating.

**EDIT:** I tried setting the specified rotation points from the linked question above. It hasn't worked for me. The triangle rotates exactly the same.

**EDIT2:** As I dive more into this, I'm starting to believe this is more than a Fabric.js question. It seems like more webGL, but not an issue, just the way shapes are transformed. I can see that there is a difference between rotating a rectangle and a triangle. Using center origins, rectangles always never appear to move around. I have not found the answer but I'm including webGL as a tag to hopefully get some help on this. Has anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fabric.js [calculates the centre point](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/601fdc9d64c7445e234a1f50a592f56943255bc5/src/mixins/object_origin.mixin.js#L71) of a shape by [translating a point in the top left corner](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/601fdc9d64c7445e234a1f50a592f56943255bc5/src/mixins/object_origin.mixin.js#L14) to the centre of the bounding box of the shape. The centre of the bounding box is not the centre of the triangle.

For an isosceles triangle (where 2 sides are the same length) with its base at the bottom - which I believe is the default for fabric.js - the centre point of the triangle is located at one third the height of the triangle.

You can use the method described [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/439#issuecomment-24029367) to find a new top-left corner (the `x` and `y` values) for the shape by rotating the original top-left about the centre of the triangle.

```
function createTriangle(x, y, angle)
{
    var width = 350;
    var height = 300;
    var pos = fabric.util.rotatePoint(
        new fabric.Point(x, y),
        new fabric.Point(x + width / 2, y + height / 3 * 2),
        fabric.util.degreesToRadians(angle)
    );
    return new fabric.Triangle(
    {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        selectable: false,
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        left: pos.x,
        top: pos.y,
        angle: angle
    });
}
```

You will need a recent version of fabric.js for this to work.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detail! I actually just found something else that was interesting. It seems that incrementing the angle causes the triangle to go around the point, rather than centering and spinning. I tried a test and in my ```requestAnimationFrame``` function, I decided to remove the triangle and create it again using an incremented angle. This way made it stay in place. Any idea why that would be? Why does 

```triangle.angle -= 0.2``` 

not equal 


```angle += 1;
    canvas.remove(triangle);
    triangle = createTriangle(300, 300, angle);
    canvas.add(triangle);```?

Comment: Wanted to add an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UW8Be/5/) to show the change for anyone who needs it for reference.